# many websites under one solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have many websites under one solution for documentation purposes. I build these small websites for prototyping new concepts that I've learned.

The problem is whenever I try to debug one of the stand-alone websites Visual Studio will start Cassini for all the websites under the solution.

I know I can create a new solution and just bring in the projects as needed but I was just wondering if there was another way to be able to see all my WebSites and debug anyone one of them at anytime without starting up Cassini for all websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making them individual solutions and just organzing my directory and making the directory names more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click on the `Solution` (not on a project), and go to `Properties`. Select `Configuration Properties` from the window on the left and untick the `Build` and/or `Deploy` properties for the projects that you want to ignore.